# Saving List of Numpy 2D arrays using numpy.save (the arrays together are jagged)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large image dataset.  When I use the images, I have several components--a mirrored image, a regular image, an eigenvector matrix and an eigenvalue vector.

I would like to store it like:

```
training_sunsets_data = [cropped_training_sunsets,
                         mirrored_training_sunsets,
                         rgb_cov_eigvec_training_sunsets,
                         rgb_cov_eigval_training_sunsets]

np.save('training_sunsets_data',training_sunsets_data)
```

And as I was writing this I was testing it (because I was sure it would fail), and the strangest thing happened when I did this: it worked.

Further, when I loaded it back up into the code, it was type ndarray, but it is a jagged array.

---

How is this possible if numpy does not allow jagged multidimensional arrays?  Did I just find a backdoor way to create a jagged array in numpy?

Comment: Can you post the jagged `ndarray` you got from loading the file? I am curious to see what it looks like.

Comment: Look at `np.savez`.  That saves each array by name in a file, and collects them in a `zip` archive.  `np.load` handles that kind of archive.

Comment: There's a very good answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603119/incremently-appending-numpy-arrays-to-a-save-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After testing on my machine:

```
  import numpy as np
  np.save('testnp.npy', [[2,3,4],[1,2]])
  np.load('testnp.npy')
  #   array([[2, 3, 4], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

As shown in the example code, the loaded object is of type `ndarray`, but its data type is `object`. That means, `np.save` store an array of python objects, which can be anything. According to the documentation, it seems to use python `pickle` to pack those objects.

So you didn't find a backdoor, it behaves just as expected.

Comment: ...and you could as well use pickle to store sets/sequences of arrays, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

np.savez() would work in your situation. save each as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

So to see what you are getting at lets runs some code.

```
>>> a =[np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> np.array(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2)
```

We see here that we are perfectly able to make a list of np.arrays of different dimensions. We cannot however cast that list into a np.array.

I suspect based on your syntax that you are saving a list, and loading a list maintaining the type np.array for each element in the list.