# Incremently appending numpy.arrays to a save file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried this method outlined by Hpaulji but it doesn't seem to working:

[How to append many numpy files into one numpy file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204368/how-to-append-many-numpy-files-into-one-numpy-file-in-python)

Basically, I'm iterating through a generator, making some changes to an array, and then trying to save the each iteration's array.

Here is what my sample code looks like:

```
filename = 'testing.npy'

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for x, _ in train_generator:
        prediction = base_model.predict(x)
        print(prediction[0,0,0,0:5])
        np.save(filename, prediction)

        current_iteration += 1
    if current_iteration == 5:
        break
```

Here, I'm going through 5 iterations, so I was hoping to save *5* different arrays.

I printed out a portion of each array, for debugging purposes:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.          3.37349415  0.          0.          1.62561738]
[  0.          20.28489304   0.           0.           0.        ]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[  0.          21.98013496   0.           0.           0.        ]
```

But when I tried to load the array, multiple times as noted here,
[How to append many numpy files into one numpy file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204368/how-to-append-many-numpy-files-into-one-numpy-file-in-python), I'm getting an EOFERROR:

```
file = r'testing.npy'

with open(file,'rb') as f:
    arr = np.load(f)
    print(arr[0,0,0,0:5])
    arr = np.load(f)
    print(arr[0,0,0,0:5])
```

It's only outputting the last array and then an EOFERROR:

```
[  0.          21.98013496   0.           0.           0.        ]
EOFError: Ran out of input

print(arr[0,0,0,0:5])
```

I was expection all 5 arrays to be saved, but when I load the save .npy file multiple times, I only get the last array.

So, how should I be saving saving and appending new array to a file?

EDIT: Testing with '.npz' only saves last array

```
filename = 'testing.npz'

current_iteration = 0
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for x, _ in train_generator:
        prediction = base_model.predict(x)
        print(prediction[0,0,0,0:5])
        np.savez(f, prediction)



        current_iteration += 1
        if current_iteration == 5:
            break


#loading

    file = 'testing.npz'

    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        arr = np.load(f)
        print(arr.keys())


>>>['arr_0']
```

Comment: as an aside, i don't know how large your date is, but have you tried HDF5, or are you tied to `.npy` for storage?

Comment: I haven't tried HDF5. I seems that is the better option( my data is about 100,000 images) but I would have to do a little more digging through the docs as I'm not as as familiar with HDF5.

Comment: ok, unfortunately i can't help with your question, but look up h5py documentation, the syntax is easy to pick up to start storing / appending numeric data, and if used correctly can be fast.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Thanks, I think I may just switch to HDF5 as it's more widely used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your calls to `np.save` use the filename, not the filehandle.
Since you do not reuse the filehandle, each save overwrites the file instead of appending the array to it.

This should work:

```
filename = 'testing.npy'

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for x, _ in train_generator:
        prediction = base_model.predict(x)
        print(prediction[0,0,0,0:5])
        np.save(f, prediction)

        current_iteration += 1
    if current_iteration == 5:
        break
```

And while there may be advantages to storing multiple arrays in one `.npy` file (I imagine advantages in situations where memory is limited), they are [technically meant](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/npy-format.html) to store one single array, and you can use `.npz` files (`np.savez` or `np.savez_compressed`) to store multiple arrays:

```
filename = 'testing.npz'
predictions = []
for (x, _), index in zip(train_generator, range(5)):
    prediction = base_model.predict(x)
    predictions.append(prediction)
np.savez(filename, predictions) # will name it arr_0
# np.savez(filename, predictions=predictions) # would name it predictions
# np.savez(filename, *predictions) # would name it arr_0, arr_1, …, arr_4
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I'm going to test it out when I get chance.

Comment: I just tried `.npz` -- `testing.npz` and  `np.savez(f, prediction)`, but it seems to be saving the last array only.   I'm loading the array the same way as the code in the OP, but I only see one key -- ['arr_0']. I will update the OP just in case I'm making a mistake.

Comment: I've added an example for npz-files. For that you only call `savez` once with all the entries (as one list of arrays or many arrays).

Comment: ＠yself  Thank you for listing out the multiple ways.

Comment: @YSelf, this is a great answer as the docs don't say anything about saving lists of np arrays.  I tried calling `np.savez(filename, next_array)` like an append to the file but obviously it does not work like that.

Comment: @YSelf, do I need to do `with open(filename, 'wb') as f:` for the npz example?  It did not work without it.

Comment: The example works as written. The first argument to `np.savez` is either a string (the filename) or a file-like (an opened file). If you pass a file-like, it has to be opened with `wb`.